# \t and \n in a String variable does not display in JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to accumulate a String in a variable but the tab and newline does not take effect.

Here is my code:

```
String message = "";

for(int i=1; i<=5; i++)
{
    message += i +"\t";
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

It only displays:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

instead of having tabs between the numbers

Comment: If there is more than one row of numbers, I'd tend to use a `JTable`.  For a single row of numbers, consider representing them in a `JList` (a single column).  More context would be helpful in providing the best advice.  At the moment, those replying & commenting are mostly guessing about the actual requirement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put the message to the JTextArea as follows.

```
String message = "";

for(int i=1; i<=5; i++){
    message += i +"\t";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, new JTextArea(message));
```

Answer (score 3):

Get use of HTML tags. `&nbsp;` is used to represent a non-breaking space character in HTML. Change your code into these statements:

```
String message = "<html>";
String tab = "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;";

for ( int i = 1; i <= 5; i++ )
    message += i + tab ;

message += "</html>";

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

You may arrange the space between the numbers via increasing/decreasing the number of `&nbsp;` entities.

Comment: Thanks for this. But is this the most efficient method to solve my problem?

Comment: @user1232352 Of course it's efficient, you are using one loop like your previous code. you can define your own tab. see my edited answer. upvote for my effort and tick accept if my answer is useful for you. thanks.

Comment: But here problem is not working \t with the showMessageDialog method, but I have checked \n and it is working fine. So anyone please guide why \t is not working with showMessageDialog. That is the answer expect from user1232352. Use of JTextArea is possible as Namal explained, but it is not appropriate with showMessageDialog.

Comment: @RuchiraKariyawasam what are you talking about? putting multiple space bars result in only one space character in display. this way is efficient. did you copy/paste/test my code. first do it and reply my post.

Comment: Using HTML, actual tab characters (rather than 5 non-breaking spaces) wrapped in a `<pre>` section would more closely match what the OP is asking.  You might also consider an HTML `<table>`.

Comment: @RuchiraKariyawasam - the OptionPane.showMessageDialog method is taking parameter "message" as type object, not just type "String" so that mean you can pass in helper classes, like Namal did in the first place, that is the correct way, and get that objects look & feel in to your MessageDialog. if you pass just a String type , you can't expect more. not even /t but few other escape characters might not work if you just pass it in as a string. it is the design but not an issue.