# creating a multiplication table using JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, joptionpane, multiplication

I have an assignment due tomorrow, I finished it, I just keep getting one error. Well its not exactly an error as much as it is my output is not the output my teacher wants.

My teacher wants me to create a multiplication table using `JOptionPane`

And this is what I have so far:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class assign3 {

public static void main(String[] args) {

        String Boundary1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the first boundary of the multiplication table.");
        String Boundary2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the second boundary of the multiplication table.");

        int X = Integer.parseInt(Boundary1);
        int Y = Integer.parseInt(Boundary2);
        int j = 1;
        String Result = "";
        int x = 1;

        while (x <= X){
            for(int i = 1;i<= Y; i++ ){
                j = i * x;
                Result = Result + j + "    ";
            }
            x++;
            Result = Result + "\n";
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Result);
    }
}
```

My output shows up like this.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/ulp1gj9sqi94d3a/IMG_20140114_162054.jpg

But my teacher wants the output to show up like this.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6gtexqoj3rs7xvl/IMG-20140114-WA0000.jpg

My code does not have the correct spacing between the digits, I have been trying to fix it somehow for sometime with no luck.

Comment: The string representation of the numbers have different lengths so you need to use different number of spaces for each. With that it is very easy to get a result _far_ better than you teachers...

Comment: JTextArea knows TAB, programatically too

Comment: Unrelated: Please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: +1 for for the effort of taking an _actual photo of your screen_ :) Take a look at [Taking Screen Shots on Mac OS X](http://guides.macrumors.com/Taking_Screenshots_in_Mac_OS_X)

Comment: And just for future notice, you should use Java naming convention - class names start with capital letters.

Comment: Are those pictures from a *phone?*  See [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) (for tips on making *great* screenshots).

Comment: I suspect the teacher used a (primitive) for of HTML to format that 2nd screenshot.  Consider wowing them and instead give them an HTML base `table`.  Though I'd probably use `JTextArea` (which respects tabs or better a `JTable` for this (note the teacher is apparently using neither of those..).

Comment: Pls refer to this similar [SO ques.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612880/t-and-n-in-a-string-variable-does-not-display-in-joptionpane-showmessagedialog)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution(assumes `result` already has needed tabs(`\t`)):

```
JTextArea jf=new JTextArea(result);

jf.setEditable(false);
jf.setOpaque(false);

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jf);
```

**EDIT:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String Boundary1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the first boundary of the multiplication table.");
        String Boundary2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the second boundary of the multiplication table.");

        int X = Integer.parseInt(Boundary1);
        int Y = Integer.parseInt(Boundary2);
        int j = 1;
        String Result = "";
        int x = 1;

        while (x <= X) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= Y; i++) {
                j = i * x;
                Result = Result + j + "\t";
            }
            x++;
            Result = Result + "\n";
        }
        JTextArea jt=new JTextArea(Result);
        jt.setEditable(false);
        jt.setOpaque(false);
        jt.setTabSize(3);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jt);
    }
```

**O/P:**
[image]

Comment: hi, thank you for your answer, however the space between each column is too big    https://www.dropbox.com/s/m5fr1nm4hqttujw/Screen%20Shot%202014-01-14%20at%205.55.22%20PM.png

Comment: @user3114770 use (with respect to my example) `jf.setTabSize(1);` or some other number

Comment: no still :( https://www.dropbox.com/s/85mn9lwxdj5bl66/Screenshot%202014-01-14%2018.32.53.png

Comment: @user3114770 I just tried my code and gives desired result...see the edit for o/p and code used

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `String.format("%5d", j)` ?

It will print each int on 5 spaces - length.

Example: `10` will be `___10`.

Or `String.format("%-5d", j)` to align to left.

Example: `10___`.

**Edit:** Another option is to use `html`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String Boundary1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the first boundary of the multiplication table.");
    String Boundary2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the second boundary of the multiplication table.");

    int X = Integer.parseInt(Boundary1);
    int Y = Integer.parseInt(Boundary2);
    int j = 1;
    String Result = "<html><table>";
    int x = 1;
    while (x <= X){
        Result += "<tr>";
        for(int i = 1;i<= Y; i++ ){

            j = i * x;
            Result += String.format("<td><center>%d</center></td>", j);
        }
        x++;
        Result = Result + "</tr>";
    }

    Result += "</table></html>";

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, Result);

}
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

Answer (score 1):

Solved

```
    public class assign3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String Boundary1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the first boundary of the multiplication table.");
        String Boundary2 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter the second boundary of the multiplication table.");

        int X = Integer.parseInt(Boundary1);
        int Y = Integer.parseInt(Boundary2);
        int j = 1;
        String Result = "    |"+"\t";
        int x = 1;

        for(int i=1;i<=Y;i++){
                Result = Result + i + "\t";
            }
            Result=Result+"\n";
            while (x <= X){
            if(x<10){
            Result=Result+ x + "  |" +"\t";
            }else{
            Result=Result+ x + "|" +"\t";

            }
            for(int i = 1;i<= Y; i++ ){
                j = i * x;
                Result = Result + j +"\t";
            }
            x++;
            Result = Result + "\n";
        }
        JTextArea jt=new JTextArea(Result);
        jt.setEditable(false);
        jt.setOpaque(false);
        jt.setTabSize(3);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jt);        
    }
    }
```

OUTPUT:

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the numbers still dont align as they should.

Comment: @user3114770 What do you mean by [https://www.dropbox.com/s/6gtexqoj3rs7xvl/IMG-20140114-WA0000.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6gtexqoj3rs7xvl/IMG-20140114-WA0000.jpg)