# why is \t not supported in joptionpane?

Tags: java, tabs, joptionpane

So my question is simple why does JOptionPane not allow you to use/not support "\t"? but does allow you to use/support "\n"?

I know how to get around this by using HTML or jTextArea ... but those methods add unnecessary code so why does oracle not add support for "\t" in JOptionPane, to help keep code simple?

For example ...

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"This is the first line" + "\n" + "This is the second line" + "\t" + "< there should be a tab here");
```

produces this ...

[image]

Which is not what should happen since i put the tab thing in correctly. So why does it happen?

Comment: Also if there are any docs on this please add a link to them because i could not find any.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9612880/t-and-n-in-a-string-variable-does-not-display-in-joptionpane-showmessagedialog) might help.

Comment: I have read that question before and that's how i know how to get the results i want but i want to know why i have to use those methods and not just use "\t".

Comment: Chances are that at some point, the method in the following link gets called, and your message gets displayed by a `JLabel`, which doesn't support `\t` : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/plaf/basic/BasicOptionPaneUI.html#addMessageComponents-java.awt.Container-java.awt.GridBagConstraints-java.lang.Object-int-boolean-